# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Address error

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have my project with the `mail.jar` in the `lib` folder. I created a manifest file as

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: mainfile
Class-Path: lib/mail.jar
```

I then exported the `jar` file using eclipse.

I tried executing the jar file now as `java -jar myjar.jar` and I get the error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Address
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How do you run the jar? The jar containing `javax.mail.Address` is not on the classpath.

Comment: Manifest file must end with a new line. Is this your case ?

Comment: I run using java -jar myjar.jar as I thought the mail.jar which contains javax.mail.Address is present in the jar and is set as classpath in the manifest file.

Comment: Open the jar with `7zip` or `WinZip` and check if it is really so.

Comment: I tried to unzip and notice the lib folder with the jar is not present. So I tried to place it directly in my project and modified classpath in my manifest. Now i see the mail.jar file in MyJar but still have the same issue

Comment: @stackuser Is your code simple? If yes, could you post it so I could generate my own jar with my Eclipse and check if I have the same problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Add `mail.jar` in your class path.
2. Make sure there is no typo in your class path.
3. Check exported `jar` file, is all required jar are came there if not you have to use eclipse option `Extract required libraries into generated JAR`.

Comment: Yes. I have mail.jar in the manifest file Class-Path . But still facing the issue.

Comment: I chose the option create runnable jar file with eclipse and extract library option and I see the jar file running now. Thanks for all help

Answer (score 1):

From the Oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html):

> The text file must end with a new line or carriage return. The last
>   line will not be parsed properly if it does not end with a new line or
>   carriage return.

So it should look something like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: lib/mail.jar
Created-By: 1.7.0_06 (Oracle Corporation)
```

Also, make sure your MANIFEST.MF inside META-INF folder.

Comment: @stackuser Is your MANIFEST.MF inside META-INF folder ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the classpath was updated and the new classpath was missing mail.jar and activation.jar

---

So linking/copying

1. mail.jar
2. activation.jar

into the classpath lib directory could be one of the solutions.

---