# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.mail.Address

Tags: java, email, spl

I am trying to send an email using Java and mail apis but I am getting run time exception as shown below.
After adding jar files to the build path and class path I am still getting the above error.

> Exception in thread "Thread-10" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.mail.Address
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.Address

Comment: Are you adding the jars in your classpath while compiling and running both? http://stackoverflow.com/a/27824693/1129313

Comment: what is your code that gets the error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Address error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27824571/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-mail-address-error)

Comment: Thanks All,I have added the jar files @ Garry